# asynchbase tutorial?

Tags: hbase

StumbleUpon has a HBase library that they call [AsynchBase](https://github.com/stumbleupon/asynchbase) - they use this for their [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) project.

It seems really useful as a library for HBase, but I can't seem to find any tutorial on AsynchBase. Does anyone know of a good one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't quite what you're looking for, but here's a scala example I threw together since the callback syntax is pretty heavy in Java:

- https://gist.github.com/2430613

Comment: I think I stumbled upon your example before posting this ques. :) I guess I am looking for a more full-blown Java example, but thanks anyway, this is useful!

Comment: Yah all my HBase stuff is in Scala, more [here](http://www.underflow.ca/blog/tag/hbase). Have you tried the default library first, it helps you get the hand of how HBase works before jumping on the async train.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked into the default library. Actually, I am just exploring the various HBase library options to find the most elegant one at this point, that's why I've been looking into async.

Comment: I think asynchbase is definitely the library to use, as far as I know it makes use of netty which means it doesn't fake it's async'ness. Your app won't use up threads waiting on replies from HBase.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit tutorial that I am aware of.  OpenTSDB is a great example of how to use the library.  There is decent detail in the [Javadoc](http://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/asynchbase/).  There are also some specific pointers for proper use that can be found on the asynchbase [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/asynchbase).

Comment: Thanks, I will probably peruse the OpenTSDB codebase then, and thanks for the pointer on the Google group.